# Web application crashes after a few requests, how to debug?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, vaadin

My Vaadin web application running on a Tomcat server using Netbeans crashes when I do something like the following in a Selenium test:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
//or: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver webdriver = new ChromeDriver(); 

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8084/myapp/");
}
```

When running this test the application becomes unresponsive and I need to restart Tomcat. I do not get any error messages (maybe I am not looking at the right places, but the log shows nothing). I would be happy to know how I can find out what goes wrong.

Edit: I was opening a database connection inside the Vaadin UI class, this caused the pool size to overflow. After I became aware of this I used jconsole to analyze the problem.

Comment: what does your app does inside? probably is doing a very heavy process that you need to optimize

Comment: Ok, I will check on this it sounds obvious but thanks for pointing into this direction. maybe creating the hibernate SessionFactory is such a "heavy" process ?

Comment: Well, I do some database access (through Hibernate) and then I show a Google Chart, but really this is nothing crazy. However I am not doing anything specific in my code to prevent such frequent requests.

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that I open/close a Hibernate Session for each request by using a ServletFilter.

Comment: that's a ridiculous statement

Comment: He winked, @IsaiahvanderElst. I think it was just a teasing joke.

Comment: Check if your 10 requests are blocked. And if they are, figure out what they are blocked on.  It could be a slow db response...

Comment: Please define "crashes", which you (maybe?) clarify later to say "becomes unresponsive". Take some thread dumps to see what the server is doing and you'll likely have your answer.

Comment: With crash I mean that unless I restart Tomcat I am not getting any response from my app. I would describe this in more detail if I knew what is going on. How to debug this problem is a main part of my question. I will try to read about blocked requests and thread dumps (I haven't heard about neither of them before).